# ASP.NET MVC npm installation error

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, npm, gruntjs

as the title says, when I'm running/saving the package.json file together with Grunt, I get this error in the "output" in Visual Studio. I've installed nodejs/npm global on my machine. But I also tried to install it through the NuGet package manager.

```
set PATH=C:\Labb projekt\MVC App\MVC Application\packages\Npm.js.2.13.1.0\build\..\tools\;%PATH%
"C:\Labb projekt\MVC App\MVC Application\packages\Npm.js.2.13.1.0\build\..\tools\npm" install
```

Why does this occur and how do I fix it?

When I build/rebuild the solution, I get 1 failed, and as I mentioned before, when saving the package.json file which contains this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "autoprefixer-core": "^6.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0"
  }
```

I get:

```
====Executing command 'npm install'====


npm WARN package.json mvc@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json mvc@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-concat@0.5.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-postcss@0.7.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.5
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-uglify@0.7.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Labb projekt\MVC App\MVC Application\MVC Application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm

====npm command completed with exit code 1====
```

Comment: Isn't the error obvious? I mean it says the version of grunt (^1.0.1) is different from what grunt-contrib-* modules want. How did you figure out which versions you want? Did you check they're compatible?

Comment: Yes, I didn't read it thorough... I fixed the issue! @Molda